# If $\mathbb{E}|X_n|=O(a_n)$, how large is $Y_n = X_n\ln\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics, probability-limit-theorems

I asked this question on crossvalidated, but it may be more appropriate to post it here.

If $\mathbb{E}|X_n|=O(a_n)$, where $a_n\to 0$ and $X_n$ is a sequence of positive random variables, how  large is $Y_n = X_n\ln\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)$?

My attempt: by Markov's inequality $\mathbb{E}|X_n|=O(a_n)$ implies $X_n=O_p(a_n)$ and $Y_n = O_p(a_n)\ln\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)$. It remains to asses $\ln\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)$. For some positive sequence of random variables $Z_n=O_p(1)$

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
X_n = a_nZ_n& \iff \ln(X_n) = \ln(a_n) + \ln(Z_n) \\
& \iff \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)} = \frac{\ln(Z_n)}{\ln(a_n)} + 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so if we show that the right side is bounded in probability we are done, since $a_n\to 0$.

By definition $Z_n = O_p(1)$ if any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M<\infty$ such that 
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Pr\left(Z_n>M\right)<\varepsilon.$$

It follows that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $L=\ln(M)$ such that
$$\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\Pr\left(\ln Z_n>L\right)<\varepsilon,$$
so $\ln Z_n = O_p(1)$ and
$$Y_n = O_p\left(a_n\ln\left(\frac{1}{a_n}\right)\right).$$

Are there flaws in my reasoning? Is there a simpler way to see this result?

My second question is whether we can say something about the order in expectation
$$\mathbb{E}\left|X_n\ln\left(\frac{1}{X_n}\right)\right| = O(?)?$$

Since 
$$\ln(x) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}(x-1)^j,$$
it looks like having only the first moment in expectation is not sufficient. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the expectation of $-X_n\log X_n$ need not exist just because we have first moments.  Consider for instance taking $$P[X_n = k] \propto \frac{1}{k^2 \log(k)^2} \qquad \text{ for }k \geq n \geq 2.$$

Then $E[X_n]$ is finite and goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ but $E[-X_n \log X_n]$ doesn't exist since you get the sum $\frac{1}{k \log (k)}$ which diverges.